# Expanding a dictionary using dot notation

Tags: python, recursion

I have the following json document:

```
{
    "id": "5c26321bd8f4113d43b91141", 
    "idMemberCreator": "5b203bc7e47d817a8138bc37", 
    "data": {
        "list": {
            "name": "Sorji for QA", 
            "id": "5b0a2543b89acdbdb85f7b42"
        }, 
        "board": {
            "shortLink": "iyCzZ5jx", 
            "name": "FlicksIO", 
            "id": "5b0a251f68a9e74b8ec3b3ac"
        }, 
        "card": {
            "shortLink": "vOt2vO7v", 
            "idShort": 92, 
            "name": "New column in main for Storefront provider correlation.", 
            "id": "5b9c0023533f7c26424ea4ed", 
            "closed": true
        }, 
        "old": {
            "closed": false
        }
    }, 
    "type": "updateCard", 
    "date": "2018-12-28T14:24:27.455Z", 
    "limits": {}, 
    "memberCreator": {
        "id": "5b203bc7e47d817a8138bc37", 
        "avatarHash": "73bfa48c76c3c92615fe89ff79a6c5ae", 
        "avatarUrl": "https://trello-avatars.s3.amazonaws.com/73bfa48f79a6c5ae", 
        "fullName": "Marie Bond", 
        "idMemberReferrer": null, 
        "initials": "MB", 
        "username": "mb"
    }
}
```

I would like to expand this out to be a single level with dot notation. That is, it should look like:

```
{
    "id": "5c26321bd8f4113d43b91141", 
    "idMemberCreator": "5b203bc7e47d817a8138bc37", 
    "data.list.name": "Sorji for QA", 
    "data.list.id": "5b0a2543b89acdbdb85f7b42"
    "data.board.shortLink": "iyCzZ5jx", 
    "data.board.name": "FlicksIO", 
    "data.board.id": "5b0a251f68a9e74b8ec3b3ac"
    "data.card.shortLink": "vOt2vO7v", 
    "data.card.idShort": 92, 
    "data.card.name": "New column in main for Storefront provider correlation.", 
    "data.card.id": "5b9c0023533f7c26424ea4ed", 
    "data.card.closed": true
    "data.old.closed": false
    "type": "updateCard", 
    "date": "2018-12-28T14:24:27.455Z", 
    "limits": {}, 
    "memberCreator.id": "5b203bc7e47d817a8138bc37", 
    "memberCreator.avatarHash": "73bfa48c76c3c92615fe89ff79a6c5ae", 
    "memberCreator.avatarUrl": "https://trello-avatars.s3.amazonaws.com/73bfa48f79a6c5ae", 
    "memberCreator.fullName": "Marie Bond", 
    "memberCreator.idMemberReferrer": null, 
    "memberCreator.initials": "MB", 
    "memberCreator.username": "mb"
}
```

Would it be possible to do this with a generator object? I've been working a lot on recursion today, and have been trying to move from `while` loops to using generator objects and yields, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can keep a parameter in the signature of the recursive function to store the paths:

```
data = {'id': '5c26321bd8f4113d43b91141', 'idMemberCreator': '5b203bc7e47d817a8138bc37', 'data': {'list': {'name': 'Sorji for QA', 'id': '5b0a2543b89acdbdb85f7b42'}, 'board': {'shortLink': 'iyCzZ5jx', 'name': 'FlicksIO', 'id': '5b0a251f68a9e74b8ec3b3ac'}, 'card': {'shortLink': 'vOt2vO7v', 'idShort': 92, 'name': 'New column in main for Storefront provider correlation.', 'id': '5b9c0023533f7c26424ea4ed', 'closed': True}, 'old': {'closed': False}}, 'type': 'updateCard', 'date': '2018-12-28T14:24:27.455Z', 'limits': {}, 'memberCreator': {'id': '5b203bc7e47d817a8138bc37', 'avatarHash': '73bfa48c76c3c92615fe89ff79a6c5ae', 'avatarUrl': 'https://trello-avatars.s3.amazonaws.com/73bfa48f79a6c5ae', 'fullName': 'Marie Bond', 'idMemberReferrer': None, 'initials': 'MB', 'username': 'mb'}}
def dot_paths(d, _paths = []):
  for a, b in d.items():
    if not b or not isinstance(b, dict):
      yield ['.'.join(_paths+[a]), b]
    else:
      yield from dot_paths(b, _paths+[a])
```

---

```
import json
print(json.dumps(dict(dot_paths(data)), indent=4))
```

Output:

```
{
"id": "5c26321bd8f4113d43b91141",
"idMemberCreator": "5b203bc7e47d817a8138bc37",
"data.list.name": "Sorji for QA",
"data.list.id": "5b0a2543b89acdbdb85f7b42",
"data.board.shortLink": "iyCzZ5jx",
"data.board.name": "FlicksIO",
"data.board.id": "5b0a251f68a9e74b8ec3b3ac",
"data.card.shortLink": "vOt2vO7v",
"data.card.idShort": 92,
"data.card.name": "New column in main for Storefront provider correlation.",
"data.card.id": "5b9c0023533f7c26424ea4ed",
"data.card.closed": true,
"data.old.closed": false,
"type": "updateCard",
"date": "2018-12-28T14:24:27.455Z",
"limits": {},
"memberCreator.id": "5b203bc7e47d817a8138bc37",
"memberCreator.avatarHash": "73bfa48c76c3c92615fe89ff79a6c5ae",
"memberCreator.avatarUrl": "https://trello-avatars.s3.amazonaws.com/73bfa48f79a6c5ae",
"memberCreator.fullName": "Marie Bond",
"memberCreator.idMemberReferrer": null,
"memberCreator.initials": "MB",
"memberCreator.username": "mb"
}
```

Comment: Elegant. Except for the big red warning signs that flash in my mind's eye whenever I see a mutable instance used as a parameter default value.  It's OK in this case because you don't make any in-place changes to `_paths` but IMO it's a bad habit leading to nasty gotchas.  Can be avoided by using `_paths=()` or `*_paths` and adapting accordingly.